# Matlab - Speeding up a Nested For Loop

Tags: matlab

A simple question, but I'm not so great with MATLAB. I have vectors `x`, (n x 1) `y`, (m x 1) and `w = [x;y]`. I want to define `M` (n+m x 1) as M(i) = number of elements of x that are less than or equal to w(i) (w is sorted). This just isn't cutting it:

```
N = n + m;
M = zeros(N,1);
for i = 1:N
  for j = 1:n
    if x(j) <= w(i)
      M(i) = M(i) + 1;
    end
  end
end
```

It's not a particularly smart way to do it, and some of my data vectors m and n are around 100000.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you ran the profiler? Where does it say the problem is? No pre-mature optimization!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This may look cryptic, but it should give you the same result as your nested loops:

```
M = histc(-x(:)',[-fliplr(w(:)') inf]);
M = cumsum(fliplr(M(1:N)))';
```

The above assumes `w` has been sorted in ascending order.

### Explanation

Your sorted vector `w` can be thought of as bin edges to use in creating a histogram with the [HISTC](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/histc.html) function. Once you count the number of values that fall in each bin (i.e. between the edges), a cumulative sum over those bins using the [CUMSUM](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/cumsum.html) function will give you your vector `M`. The reason the above code looks so messy (with negations and the function [FLIPLR](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/fliplr.html) in it) is because you want to find values in `x` *less than or equal to* each value in `w`, but the function [HISTC](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/histc.html) bins data in the following way:

> `n(k)` counts the value `x(i)` if `edges(k)
>   <= x(i) < edges(k+1)`.

Notice that *less than* is used for the upper limit of each bin. You would want to flip the behavior so that you bin according to the rule `edges(k) < x(i) <= edges(k+1)`, which can be achieved by negating the values to be binned, negating the edges, flipping the edges (since the edge input to [HISTC](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/histc.html) must be monotonically nondecreasing), and then flipping the bin counts returned. The value [`inf`](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/inf.html) is used as an edge value to count everything less than the lowest value in `w` in the first bin.

If you wanted to find values in `x` that are simply *less than* each value in `w`, the code would be much simpler:

```
M = histc(x(:)',[-inf w(:)']);
M = cumsum(M(1:N))';
```

Comment: This solution is the correct one, using histc. However, it will fail if w is not in a sorted order. histc will then return an error. I would also not be surprised if it would fail if there were replicates in w.

Comment: if w is already sorted then a simple `unique` would resolve that issue  relatively quickly

Comment: @woodchips: True, the solution assumes `w` is already sorted. However, if there are replicates in `w` I believe it will return the same answer as the nested for loops in the question. The edges of the bins will still be monotonically nondecreasing, and bins that have the same value for each edge should end up with a count of 0.

Comment: gnovice, then your solution is incorrect.  the `for` loop in the OP's question will repeat the counts, so where `w(i) = w(j)` for `j = i + 1` you should have `M(i) = M(j)`, though here you would have `M(j) = 0 != M(i)`.

Comment: @Mark: The call to CUMSUM after the binning takes care of that.

Comment: +1 and check: Wow. I have a long way to go with my MATLAB. Fast and appears to work correctly on several test cases.

Answer (score 5):

At a minimum the inner loop can be replaced with:

```
M(i)=sum(x<=w(i))
```

this will provide substantial performance improvement. You might then consider using arrayfun:

```
M = arrayfun(@(wi)( sum( x <= wi ) ), w);
```

arrayfun is less likely to provide substantial gains over the outer for loop but might be worth a try.

edit: I should note that neither `w` or `x` need to be sorted for this operation to work correctly.

edit: fwiw, I decided to do some actual performance testing, so I ran this program:

n = 100000;
    m = n;

```
N = n + m;

x = rand(n, 1);
w = [x; rand(m, 1)];

tic;
M = zeros(N,1);
for i = 1:N
  for j = 1:n
    if x(j) <= w(i)
      M(i) = M(i) + 1;
    end
  end
end
perf = toc;
fprintf(1, 'Original : %4.3f sec\n', perf);

w = sort(w); % presorted, so don't incur time cost;
tic;
M = histc(-x(:)',[-fliplr(w(:)') inf]);
M = cumsum(fliplr(M(1:N)))';
perf = toc;
fprintf(1, 'gnovice : %4.3f sec\n', perf);

tic;
M = zeros(N,1);
for i = 1:N
    M(i)=sum(x<=w(i));
end
perf = toc;
fprintf(1, 'mine/loop : %4.3f sec\n', perf);

tic;
M = arrayfun(@(wi)( sum( x <= wi ) ), w);
perf = toc;
fprintf(1, 'mine/arrayfun : %4.3f sec\n', perf);
```

and got these results for n = 1000:

```
Original : 0.086 sec
gnovice : 0.002 sec
mine/loop : 0.042 sec
mine/arrayfun : 0.070 sec
```

and for n = 100000:

```
Original : too long to tell ( >> 1m )
gnovice : 0.050 sec
mine/loop : too long to tell ( >> 1m )
mine/arrayfun : too long to tell ( >> 1m )
```

Comment: +1: Nice job testing the timing. I'm pretty sure the results should be the same for the different solutions, but did you double-check that they are equal?

Answer (score 1):

Haven't done MATLAB for a while, but this should function:

- Sort x with the inbuilt sort algorithm upwards.
- Use a loop with wandering index to iterate only one-time over x(j)

  ```
  j = 1;
  for i = 1:N
    while j <= n && x(j) <= w(i)
      M(i) = M(i) + 1;
      j = j+1;
    end
  end
  ```
- Finally accumulate the sum

  ```
  for j =2:n
    M(j) = M(j-1) + M(j)
  end
  ```

Comment: Two points: 1) I think the line `j = 1;` should go outside the for loop. 2) Your sum accumulation loop can be replaced with a call to CUMSUM.

Comment: Right, but anyway your solution seems to be the final one, so I don't think I need to correct my answer...

Comment: @Thorsten: In truth, I would imagine that the inner workings of the HISTC function I used in my solution might be similar to your first two bullet points. You're doing the binning yourself, which means you could avoid the somewhat messy extra work I had to do to change between `<` and `<=`. I wouldn't be surprised if the run time for our two solutions were similar.

Answer (score 1):

try this one instead:

```
M = sum( bsxfun(@le, w', sort(w)) , 2 )
```

Comment: I wasn't aware of this function! Useful, but I get an out of memory error.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Matlab in front of me so I can't confirm that this is 100% functional, but you might want to try something like:

```
for i = 1:N
    M(i) = arrayfun(@(ary,val)length(find(ary <= val)), x, w(i))
end
```

Comment: After seeing Amro's post, I noticed that you can replace my `length(find(...))` by a simple `sum(...)`.

Comment: arrayfun requires the inputs to be the same length, but I think that:

    for i = 1:N
      M(i) = sum(arrayfun(@(ary,val)sum(ary <= val), x,ones(n,1)*w(i)));
    end

is a similar idea. Thanks! (no idea why my code isn't formatting properly).

Comment: I know the `<=` operator will implicitly make the scalar into a vector as you have done, and I just assumed `arrayfun` would do so as well.  I guess that shows you what you make out of "u" and me when you assume :).

Comment: The inner portion can be written much more concisely as `M(i) = sum(x <= w(i))`, there's no need to use `arrayfun` and you can take advantage of Matlab's vectorized operations.