# how can we overcome the buffer limitations in octave?

Tags: octave

when we tried to implement a program with one for loop with a limit of 100,octave failed to show all the results.this is the problem with buffer. how can we overcome that?

Comment: please show your code, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to express the problem in terms of matrices. MATLAB and Octave are optimized for matrix operations. Here is an excerpt of what the MATLAB documentation site says about [vectorizing loops](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f8-784135.html#br8fs0d-1):

> The MATLAB software uses a matrix language, which means it is designed for vector and matrix operations. You can often speed up your code by using vectorizing algorithms that take advantage of this design. *Vectorization* means converting `for` and `while` loops to equivalent vector or matrix operations.

They also provide a simple example of vectorizing a loop to compute the sine of 1001 values ranging from 0 to 10:

```
i = 0;
for t = 0:.01:10
    i = i + 1;
    y(i) = sin(t);
end
```

To a vectorized version of the same code:

```
t = 0:.01:10;
y = sin(t);
```

There are more details in the MATLAB [Code Vectorization Guide](http://www.mathworks.com/support/tech-notes/1100/1109.html)
and some examples in these few related questions:

- [Loopless function calls on vector/matrix members in Matlab/Octave](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2470844/448455)
- [Matlab - Speeding up a Nested For Loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2016621/448455)